# Incorporating variables in UI scripting for applescript with object scripts

Tags: user-interface, object, scripting, applescript

I have a script that involves some UI Scripting to target a phone number in an in-house application that does not support applescript (thus why I must UI Script). The part which I have successfully written is as follows:

```
tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "Ticket Tracker" to true
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Ticket Tracker"
try
    try
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 14 of group 1 
        of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of window 1

        if the_number = "" then
            set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 1 of 
            splitter group 1 of window 1
        end if 
    on error
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of combo box 3 of 
        tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2 of 
        splitter group 1 of window 1
            if the_number = "" then
                set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 11 
                of tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2
                of splitter group 1 of window 1
            end if
    end try
```

The second half of this code is to try and grab the number from the 2nd newly opened window. When the first window is opened and that is the window you want to grab the number from, then "window 1" is a perfectly fine index. But if you open a new window, and your second window (the first one opened) is the one you want to grab the number from, then you have to look for "window 2", that is why I combined the first block of code with the second and tied it together with **try** and **on error** as you can see...

```
on error
    try
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 14 
        of group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 
        of window 2

        if the_number = "" then
            set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 1 
            of splitter group 1 of window 2
        end if
    on error
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of combo box 3 of 
        tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2
        of splitter group 1 of window 2

        if the_number = "" then
            set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 11 
            of tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2
            of splitter group 1 of window 2
        end if
    end try
end try
end tell
end tell
```

This was a good starter concept, however other people who would use my script operate the "Ticket Tracker" application differently and would require me to search for "window indexes" as high as 6 or 7.

What I want to do is write a script object that uses the first half of the block of code that I have, and then if it fails to find "window x" to try to find "window x + 1" and to continue to try until it succeeds (with a limit of about 20). I am very new to script objects and still trying to grasp the concept but this is what I have so far:

```
Script indexFinder
property x : 1

to tryAgain
    set x to x + 1
try
    try
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 14 of group 1 
        of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of window x

        if the_number = "" then
            set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 1 of 
            splitter group 1 of window x
        end if 
    on error
        set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of combo box 3 of 
        tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2 of 
        splitter group 1 of window x

        if the_number = "" then
            set the_number to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 11 
            of tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2
            of splitter group 1 of window x
        end if
    end try
on error
    repeat tryAgain
end try
end tryAgain
end script
```

I'm not sure if this syntax is correct but I think it encapsulates what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Why do you think you need a new script object?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure if object was the right terminology. I will gladly make the appropriate edits to this question. Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible.

Comment: I think I see what you were trying to do with a script object. A handler is more appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
set maxWindow to 20

repeat with i from 1 to maxWindow
    try
        set the_number to tTracker(i)
        exit repeat
    end try
end repeat

-- insert the rest of your script
return the_number

-- Handlers
on tTracker(windowNumber)
    try

        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of process "Ticket Tracker" to true
            tell process "Ticket Tracker"
                set xxx to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 14 of group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of window windowNumber

                if xxx = "" then
                    set xxx to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 1 of splitter group 1 of window windowNumber
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
        return xxx

    on error
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Ticket Tracker"
            set xxx to value of attribute "AXvalue" of combo box 3 of tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of window windowNumber
            if xxx = "" then
                set xxx to value of attribute "AXvalue" of static text 11 of tab group 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 2 of splitter group 1 of window windowNumber
            end if
        end tell
        return xxx

    end try
end tTracker
```

Comment: I tested it today and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. Thanks for the answer. It really helps me grasp handlers and understand when to use them.